# MySql Stored Procedure or Function?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm working in a Silverlight 5 environment with RIA services and a Mysql Database. I have a table that has about 20 different locations stored in it. I need to check each record for a possible string match in everyone one of the possible twenty locations using either a Contains or LIKE.  If a location match is found in a record, I only need a few fields from that record. Not the data from the other 19 locations. If there is no match in the record being checked nothing is saved.  I'm at a loss with RIA. I could write a  query with 20 or's but when a match is found the entire record will be returned, which is to be displayed in a datagrid and since the search field may be in 1 of 20 locations I can't just hide the unwanted fields.  Can a nested loop routine be saved in a Mysql function or procedure so that the entity framework can just query it?  If so, could you give me a syntax push in the right direction.  Thx in advance.

Comment: Why not read the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-procedure.html) first?

Comment: Is this one string in any of the 20? If so you just concatenate them and the do a like on that. Performance is going to be far from brilliant though.

Answer (score 0):

For example sake, let me assume column names as `col1`, `col2`, ..., `col20` in `your_table`.

Following query may help you to fetch first found matched column value in a record.

```
SET @criteria='%searh criteria%'; -- search string
SET @none_matched=NULL; -- use this alternative if none matched
SELECT 
 IF( col1 like @criteria, col1,
     IF( col2 like @criteria, col2,
        IF( col3 like @criteria, col3,
--          // 'if's until 'col20'
            @none_matched ) ... ) as 'your_label' -- make sure you have 20 closing braces
FROM your_table;
```

I am not sure about the performance using this type of query.
Alternatively you can depend on a stored procedure.